# SQL clients and employees

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a database that has two tables in it - Clients and Employees. The clients are served by the employees. I want to make a relationship between them. Should I make a third table for this problem, or make a column ServedByEmployee in the clients table? I want explaination also, not only answer :)

Comment: It entirely depends on what your needs are. Is it a many:1 or 1:1 relationship? If so, no need for an extra table (just a column in one of the tables to identify how they're related, possibly with a foreign key). If it's a many to many relationship, make an extra table to record relationships.

Comment: it depends on what kind of relation you´ll have... if you have many to many you may want to have a relation table...

Comment: so basically everytime i need a many to many relationship i have to make a new table, and if it's one to many i use a column ?

Comment: In general, yes. Creating an extra table for a many:1 or 1:1 relationship is superfluous and more confusing than it needs to be, IMO. e.g. if an employee can have many clients but a client can only have one employee, then putting a `servedByEmployee` column in the client table makes more sense than creating an entirely separate table for the same purpose. There _might_ be a use case for an extra table if it's recording other things (for example, say you want to record the history if the employee can change, then you might want a separate table for that which includes dates).

Comment: Basically, it all comes down to knowing what information you want to have, then planning around that in the most efficient way. You need to decide whether your needs can be satisfied by just creating a column or whether you need to record it all in a separate table because there's extra information you want to capture.

Comment: btw i am getting a little confused sometimes with these relationships... Since for example i can say many employees can have many clients, but respectively i can say one employee can have many clients and if logically thinking it is the same thing...

Comment: X:Y relationships usually refer to separate categories of items (in this case, separate categories of people). Employees are one category. Clients are another. You only care about the relationship between these two categories. Can an employee (potentially) have multiple clients (at once)? Can a client (potentially) be catered to by multiple employees (at once)? These are the only things you care about when thinking of an "X:Y" relationship between employees and clients.

Comment: So when thinking it in my head i should think in singular?

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess singular within a category. You only care about whether a single employee can have multiple clients and whether a single client can have multiple employees. For example, if a single employee can have many clients but a single client can only have one employee, then it's described as many to one (or one to many, whichever).